# Nifi PutSQL limit records and stay in queue

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I'm trying to write in a table 100000 records with PutSQL component but it always limit the number of records written to 20000 whatever I do with the settings.
[PutSQL limitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpQ4J.png)

The only way to work is to stop and empty manually many times the ouput queue.

Do you have an idea what could be the problem ? I have larger tables to ingest I need to automatise.

I tried to raise the batch size but same issue. I put the support Fragmented Trasactions to false otherwise it wasn't passing through at all [putSQL setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfbzI.png)

It workd fine with smaller ingestions records than 20000.

thanks,
Cédric

Comment: I prefer use a https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord

Comment: Try increasing concurrent tasks and run duration for `PutSQL` and keep batch size default